# Understanding generation of 52 card ojects

Tags: c#, list, object

I have managed to output 52 different "cards" to the console however the checks I performed to see if I was generating individual objects seem to indicate I have gone wrong somewhere.
Such as my num constructor not incrementing as cards are created and also when I iterate through my list with a foreach loop, the cards all have the value 13. I believe it is where I am adding my card to the deck but I am not entirely sure.

Sorry if this is a newbie question that has been answered before!

``````
    {
        public int Suite 
        public int Value 
        public string cardString;
        public int num;
        public Card ()
        { num++; }

      public static void GenerateDeck()
        {
            List<Card> Deck = new List<Card>();
            for (int c = 1; c < 5; c++)
            {
                Card card = new Card();
                {
                    card.Suite = c;                   
                }
                for (int k = 1 ; k <=13; k++)
                {
                    card.Value = k;
                    {
                        switch (card.Suite)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                card.cardString = "Hearts";
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                card.cardString = "Diamonds";
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                card.cardString = "Spades";
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                card.cardString = "Clubs";
                                break;

                        }                   

                        if (card.Value == 1)
                        {
                            card.cardString = "Ace of " + card.cardString;                            
                        }
                        else if (card.Value > 0 && card.Value <= 10)
                        {
                            card.cardString = card.Value.ToString() + " of " + card.cardString;                                                      
                        }
                        else if (card.Value == 11)
                        {
                            card.cardString = "Jack of " + card.cardString;
                        }
                        else if (card.Value == 12)
                        {
                            card.cardString = "Queen of " + card.cardString;
                        }
                        else if (card.Value == 13)
                        { card.cardString = "King of " + card.cardString; }

                        Deck.Add(card);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(card.cardString);                  
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            foreach (var item in Deck)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CARD SUITE {0} AND CARD VALUE {1}, num{2} ", item.Suite, item.Value, item.num                    
                    );
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Deck.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
`````
``````

Comment: You are reusing the card object. You construct it once for each suite, but then reuse it for all the 13 cards in that suite. You need to move the construction of the card object inside the innermost loop.

Comment: In other words, you are constructing 4 distinct card objects, then assign values to each 13 times, and add the card objects 13 times each to your list. Which means you will end up with 13 kings of heart, 13 kings of spades, 13 kings of ... etc.

Comment: If you don't know the difference between a reference type (class) and a value type (struct), you should definitely google these topics and read up on them.

Comment: Thankyou very much, is a Card class a bad way of doing this? I have sucseeded in writing a similar program generating "people" with an age and a height and a unique ID but i was not using nested loops for this task.

Comment: No, a Card class is fine. You just need to learn how reference types work (a fundamentally important concept).

Comment: ^ What @MatthewWatson said.

Comment: Thankyou so much for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Like J.A.I.L points out in his answer you only create 4 objects.

To solve your problem you need to create a new `Card`-object for every iteration of the inner loop, like:

```
for (int c = 1; ...)
{
    for (int k = 1; ...)
    {
        var card = new Card()
        card.Suite = c;
        card.Value = k;
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work now! 

` int Counter = 0;
            List<Card> Deck = new List<Card>();
            for (int c = 1; c < 5; c++)
            {
                Counter = c;
              
                
                for (int k = 1 ; k <=13; k++)
                {
                    Card card = new Card();
                    card.Suite = Counter;
                    card.Value = k;
                    {
                        switch (card.Suite)
                        {`

                           etc....

Comment: @DavidGreen you don't need to store `c` in an extra variable if you only use its value inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are only creating 4 new cards:

```
           for (int c = 1; c < 5; c++)
            {
                Card card = new Card();
                {
                    card.Suite = c;

                }
```

Then, after each of those 4 cars are created, you are adding *the same* card instance 13 times. You are also changing the value of that instance 13 times so you'll end up with a `Deck` with 13 instances of the same card object (all of them being Kings):

```
                Card card = new Card();
                { /*...*/ } 
                for (int k = 1 ; k <=13; k++)
                {
                    card.Value = k;
                    // ... 
                    Deck.Add(card);
                }
```

To solve your problem you have to create each card inside the for "values" loop:

```
           for (int c = 1; c < 5; c++)
           {
                for (int k = 1 ; k <=13; k++)
                {
                     Card card = new Card();
                     // ... Set here the Value and Suite
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create card *once*, in the inmost loop; something like this

```
  // Possible Suits
  string[] suits = new string[] { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

  // Possible Values: 3 groups combined
  string[] values = new string[] { "Ace" }                     // Ace
    .Concat(Enumerable.Range(2, 9).Select(c => c.ToString()))  // 2..10
    .Concat(new string[] { "Jack", "Queen", "King" })          // Jack, Queen, King
    .ToArray();

  // For each combination of Suit and value ...
  for (int suitIndex = 0; suitIndex < suits.Length; ++suitIndex)
    for (int valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < values.Length; ++valueIndex) {
      // ... we creare a card and add it to deck
      Card card = new Card() {
        Suite = suitIndex + 1,  // + 1 - since arrays are zero based
        Value = valueIndex + 1,
        cardString = $"{values[valueIndex]} of {suits[suitIndex]}"
      };

      Deck.Add(card);

      // Debug purpose only
      Console.WriteLine(card.cardString);  
    }
```

Comment: I would even use `Card`'s constructor to provide Suite and Value and make the properties read-only. That prevents these kind of errors (and will prevent that later on, somebody changes his cards to all aces ;-)

Comment: @PMF: Me too :) `Card` should be *immutable*: once created is must not be changed